# Is indentation in answer editor broken?

Tags: support, stack-snippets, code-formatting

I edited [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881441/can-you-get-the-number-of-lines-of-code-from-a-github-repository/32154303#32154303), and by the look of the things, I cannot understand what went wrong. The code is indented with spaces, but they somehow disappear in preview.

What did I do wrong?

(It's very likely my fault, but UX is not that good. I don't think users should end up in such situations.)

Comment: The entire code isn’t indented by four spaces. I’m surprised this even works. Unindented lines of code are automatically treated as code by the snippet, but indented lines of code remain unchanges; since code that doesn’t use `\`\`\``-style fences requires four spaces of indentation, the already-indented code lines appear unindented in the final result. So a fix for this particular post would be to simply indent all of the code by four spaces (or, maybe, edit the snippet and save again). Other than that, I’m not sure if this should be a bug report…

Comment: It seems to work if you click on _edit the above snippet_ and use the stack snippet editor.

Comment: I finally fixed it. Thanks! Now the question is how to improve UX in this place. I don't think it *should* have worked, if that kind of syntax is not allowed. Magically disappearing indentation with no error message doesn't explain anything.

Comment: There is a [new rich text editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor) that will be released shortly and is currently in beta test. It is expected that it will simplify code formatting

Comment: When editing snippets, I highly recommend opening up the snippet editor proper. It makes making these sorts of mistakes impossible, and only takes a second longer. Many times when I've tried editing a snippet using just Markdown, I've regretted it when there's been more than a character or two to change.

Comment: @charlietfl I'm not trying to be pedantic, but the title of that post clearly indicates that the new editor is in *alpha* testing, not beta, which is a notable difference. [We're months away](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360033/opt-in-alpha-test-for-a-new-stacks-editor#comment1201795_360142) from getting that editor, if we ever get it.